# Reload view after iOS 9 back button pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, reload

I'm looking for reload view after the back button was pressed.

Scrip : 
If location is disable, the user can open settings with button. When it's done the user can press the back button (if iOS9), or go back in the app with the multitask. After this, I want to reload the with (and change my text + delete my button).

How to do this ?

I'v already try something to search the good place to do it :

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"load");
}
```

or viewDidAppear, but no one are called.

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case, the proper solution is to have the view controller register for the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification. When this is sent, you can check location permissions as needed.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer to indicate your question has been answered.